# how to Identify which process is causing computer to freeze?

Tags: ram, memory-usage, monitoring, system-monitor

**EDIT 2**
While it didn't answer my original question, since increasing the swap to 4G I don't experience any more computer freezes, so I accepted the answer

**EDIT**

As @heyynema suggested, I ran the following operations
[image]

I'll report back in a few days whether this has solved/improved the issue

**OP**

I'm running multiple dev related processes on my machine in the background, i.e. vscode, dev servers, etc

every once in a while my laptop kinda freezes almost entirely for about 30 seconds, and then everything goes back to normal.

during the "freeze" if I move my mouse I can see the cursor moving around very slowly with a huge lag.

Is there a way to identify which process is causing this?

I don't know much about memory and monitoring, is there an alert I should set up, i.e. "if any process exceeds X memory then log Y"?

[image]

Comment: Keep system monitor open, and look at the process consuming the highest amount of memory.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `swapon -s`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema added the output of these commands :)

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I can't do that because in these "freeze" times I can't switch to any window, everything is kinda not responding

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Sry had a hectic time at work. updated OP with the outputs of your suggestions. Will report back in a few days! (and of course accept the answer if things improve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have plenty of RAM. But historically a 2G /swapfile has proven to be too small. We'll increase yours from 2G to 4G...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```